# Plot 8th roots of unity on complex plane with PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, plot

This is what I currently have

```
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal, axis lines=center,
        xlabel=$\Re$,
        ymax=1.5,ymin=-1.5,
        ylabel={$\Im$},
        domain=-10:10,samples=21,
        disabledatascaling]
        \addplot[scatter,only marks]({cos(3*pi*deg(x)/4)},{sin(3*pi*deg(x)/4)});
        \draw[help lines] (0,0) circle (1);
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{\(8^{\rm th}\) roots of unity on \(\mathbb C\)-plane}
        \label{fig:prob3}
\end{figure}
```

This produces the plot shown below,[image]

Could someone explain how I am getting the right angles. How can I change this to plot nth roots of unity for a general n. I am also not sure how to annotate the angles made by the roots with x-axis the right way with pgfplots.

Comment: This would be enough. `\addplot[scatter, only marks, domain=0:360, samples=9,] ({cos(x)},{sin(x)});`

Answer (score 5):

The code bellow allows you to tune the value of "n" in order to get any number of complex roots, it uses \pgfmathsetmacro in order to fix a value for n.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %%%% n is the value setting the number of complex roots
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{7}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal,
        axis lines=center,
        xlabel=$\Re$,
        xtick={-1.5,-0.5,0,0.5,1.5},
        ytick={0,0.5},
        xmax=1.5,
        xmin=-1.5,
        ymax=1.5,
        ymin=-1.5,
        ylabel=$\Im$,
        samples=10,
        disabledatascaling]
        \draw[help lines, black] (0,0) circle (1);
        \foreach \t in {1,...,\n} {
        \edef\temp{\noexpand
        \node[fill=blue, circle, draw=blue, scale=0.5] at ( {cos((360*\t)/\n)}, {sin((360*\t)/\n)} ) {};
         }\temp}
         \foreach \t in {1,...,\n} {
         \edef\temp{\noexpand
         \node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.7] at ( {1.25*cos((360*\t)/\n)}, {1.25*sin((360*\t)/\n)} ) {$w_{\t}$};             
          }\temp}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{$n^{th}$ roots of unity on $\mathbb{C}$-plane}
        \label{fig:prob3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way to obtain the same result is to use \pgfplotsinvokeforeach as a for loop in an axis environement. Although, the variable changing is not \t anymore but #1 like within a macro, see the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %%%% n is the value setting the number of complex roots
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{7}
        \begin{axis}[axis equal,
        axis lines=center,
        xlabel=$\Re$,
        xtick={-1.5,-0.5,0,0.5,1.5},
        ytick={0,0.5},
        xmax=1.5,
        xmin=-1.5,
        ymax=1.5,
        ymin=-1.5,
        ylabel=$\Im$,
        samples=10,
        disabledatascaling]
\draw[help lines, black] (0,0) circle (1);
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\n}{
\node[fill=blue, circle, draw=blue, scale=0.5] at ( {cos((360* #1)/\n)}, {sin((360* #1)/\n)} ) {};}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\n}{
\node[fill=white, circle, draw=none, scale=0.7] at ( {1.25*cos((360* #1)/\n)}, {1.25*sin((360* #1)/\n)} ) {$w_{#1}$};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{$n^{th}$ roots of unity on $\mathbb{C}$-plane}
\label{fig:prob3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Hope that it is what you were looking for.

Romain

Comment: Very good answer. You picture is fine. +1.